# Replace img with click link

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, href

I have 3 img pic and 3 link. Every link have own pic. I want replace pic when click on link. Now it replace but it restart window. I dont want restart.

```
<div class="home-actions" >
    <img class="home-actions__img" src="{{asset('images/ohdaihiep/block3/bg3_1.jpg')}}" alt="" id="my_image" >
    <a href="#" id="my_a"  class="home-actions__bg3-1" ></a>
    <a href="#" id="my_a2" class="home-actions__bg3-2" ></a>
    <a href="#" id="my_a3" class="home-actions__bg3-3" ></a>
</div>
```

And my jQuery code

```
$(function () {
    $("#my_a").bind("click", function () {
        $("#my_image").attr("src", "images/ohdaihiep/block3/bg3_1.jpg");
    });
    $("#my_a2").bind("click", function () {
        $("#my_image").attr("src", "images/ohdaihiep/block3/bg3_2.png");
    });
    $("#my_a3").bind("click", function () {
        $("#my_image").attr("src", "images/ohdaihiep/block3/bg3_3.jpg");
    });
```

Comment: To the click function pass `event` and do `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: Why use a link for this? Use a `<button type="button">

Comment: I was late with the answer about preventDefaul

Comment: design :) can not cut HTML and dont' have separatelly in photoshop. Idea change background when click link

Comment: @kerbh0lz, sometimes it may be a customer request.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov Could be, but I highly doubt that a customer _requested_ these to be links. Even if so, one could tell your customer that links should point to a different URL or section within a document and that a button element was made for just that: execute some action/code when clicked - and there's no need for `preventDefault()` when using a button.

Comment: You can use simple : `<a href="javascript:" ...` to avoid this behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is how it will not restart

```
$("#my_a").bind("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#my_image").attr("src","images/ohdaihiep/block3/bg3_1.jpg");
});
$("#my_a2").bind("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#my_image").attr("src","images/ohdaihiep/block3/bg3_2.png");
});
$("#my_a3").bind("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#my_image").attr("src","images/ohdaihiep/block3/bg3_3.jpg");
});
```

Comment: thank you so much !!!! I so tired with it for today!

Comment: @OlegSt If this answer solved your problem please accept is as answer so others know the solution and this question can be closed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this code I hope helpful

$("#my_a").bind("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#my_image").attr("src","images/ohdaihiep/block3/bg3_1.jpg");
});
$("#my_a2").bind("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#my_image").attr("src","images/ohdaihiep/block3/bg3_2.png");
});
$("#my_a3").bind("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#my_image").attr("src","images/ohdaihiep/block3/bg3_3.jpg");
});
```